# Detaillist deselects all selected Items if clicked on unselected Item

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

This behaviour is annoying, if you click on the checkbox for selection, it behaves correctly and adds the item to the total selection.

However if an unselected Item is clicked on outside of the checkbox the selection will reset and I end up with only that Item selected.
How can I disable this behaviour so that both clicks on the checkbox and outside of it behave the same?

Thanks